# using useEffect in combination with Axios fetching API data returns null - how to deal with this?

Tags: reactjs

Fetching data using Axios and useEffect results in null before the actual object is loaded.

Unfortunately, I am not able to use object destructuring before the actual object is not empty.

I am forced to use a hook to check whether an object is empty or not.

For instance, I would like to create multiple functions and split my code up in separate functions for better readability.

This is my HTTP request Hook:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

import axios from 'axios';

export const useHttp = (url, dependencies) => {
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
    const [fetchedData, setFetchedData] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        setIsLoading(true);

        axios
            .get(url)
            .then(response => {
                setIsLoading(false);
                setFetchedData(response.data);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Oops!', error);
                setIsLoading(false);
            });
    }, dependencies);

    return [isLoading, fetchedData];
};
```

Followed by my page component:

```
import React from 'react';

import { PAGE_ABOUT, API_URL } from 'constants/import';

import Header from './sections/Header';
import Main from './sections/Main';
import Aside from './sections/Aside';

import { useHttp } from 'hooks/http';

const About = () => {
    const [isLoading, about] = useHttp(PAGE_ABOUT, []);

    if (!isLoading && about) {
        return (
            <section className="about">
                <div className="row">
                    <Header
                        featuredImage={API_URL + about.page_featured_image.path}
                        authorImage={API_URL + about.page_author_image.path}
                        authorImageMeta={about.page_author_image.meta.title}
                        title={about.about_title}
                        subtitle={about.about_subtitle}
                    />

                    <Main
                        title={about.page_title}
                        content={about.page_content}
                    />

                    <Aside
                        title={about.about_title}
                        content={about.about_content}
                    />
                </div>
            </section>
        );
    }
};

export default React.memo(About);
```

The actual problem I am not able to nest functions before the object is actually returned.

Is there a way to fetch data without a check by any chance? or a cleaner solution would help.

I would like to use multiple components to split up the code.

Any advice or suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I'm really not sure which part of the code is causing you problems? Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: I'm in the same boat as Zeljko, I'm not sure what the actual question/problem is.

Comment: I have this "if (!isLoading && about) {"I am not able to add an arrow function outside this IF statement because it first returns null causing my app to return undefined. I would like to use object destructuring instead of having about.title, about.section i just want to use "title" and "section". And I want to split op the complete code into multiple inline components but I can't do that outside the if statement. Is there a way I can only return the data if it's loaded without the check?

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz/codesandbox demo showing the issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you are asking would be bad for UIs. You don't want to block the UI rendering when you're fetching data. So the common practice is showing a Loading spinner or (if you're counting on the request being fast) just rendering nothing until it pops up.

So you would have something like:

```
const About = () => {
    const [isLoading, about] = useHttp(PAGE_ABOUT, []);

    if (isLoading) return null; // or <Loading />

    return (
       <section className="about">
            <div className="row">
                <Header
                    featuredImage={API_URL + about.page_featured_image.path}
                    authorImage={API_URL + about.page_author_image.path}
                    authorImageMeta={about.page_author_image.meta.title}
                    title={about.about_title}
                    subtitle={about.about_subtitle}
                />

                <Main
                  title={about.page_title}
                  content={about.page_content}
                />

                <Aside
                  title={about.about_title}
                  content={about.about_content}
                />
            </div>
        </section>
    );
};
```

If your api has no protection for errors and you're afraid of about being **null** or **undefined** you can wrap the component with an [Error Boundary](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html) Component and show a default error. But that depends if you use those in your app.

> Error boundaries are React components that catch JavaScript errors
>   anywhere in their child component tree, log those errors, and display
>   a fallback UI instead of the component tree that crashed. Error
>   boundaries catch errors during rendering, in lifecycle methods, and in
>   constructors of the whole tree below them.

Answer (score 0):

You are not returnig any if your condition in our **About** component is false so add a case if  **isLoading** or **!about** you could add a loader maybe:

```
const About = () => {
    const [isLoading, about] = useHttp(PAGE_ABOUT, []);

    let conditionalComponent =  null;

    if (!isLoading && about) {
        conditionalComponent= (
            <section className="about">
                <div className="row">
                    <Header
                        featuredImage={API_URL + about.page_featured_image.path}
                        authorImage={API_URL + about.page_author_image.path}
                        authorImageMeta={about.page_author_image.meta.title}
                        title={about.about_title}
                        subtitle={about.about_subtitle}
                    />

                    <Main
                        title={about.page_title}
                        content={about.page_content}
                    />

                    <Aside
                        title={about.about_title}
                        content={about.about_content}
                    />
                </div>
            </section>
        );
    }
    return conditionalComponent

};
```

Answer (score 0):

As I recognize you want to get rid of condition `if (!isLoading && about) {`

You can make it in several ways:

1) You can create `Conditional` component by your own. This component should receive `children` prop as a function and should apply other props to this function:

```
function Conditional({ children, ...other }) {
  if (Object.entries(other).some(([key, value]) => !value)) {
    return "empty"; // null or some `<Loading />` component
  }
  return children(other);
}
```

Also I made a small demo https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-cori-ngenk

It helps you to create only the one place for condition and reuse it in dozens of components :)

2) You can use some library, which is built on a top of React.lazy and React.Suspense (but it wouldn't work on a server-side). 
For example https://dev.to/charlesstover/react-suspense-with-the-fetch-api-374j and a library: https://github.com/CharlesStover/fetch-suspense